# How to make my app a device owner?

Tags: android, device-admin

The [device policy manager API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isDeviceOwnerApp%28java.lang.String%29) and the [android 5.0 overview](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Enterprise) both mention something about a **device owner app**.  How can I setup my app as a *device owner*?

Edit:
Is there any other ways than rooting and NFC if available please share.

Comment: From the link --->A device owner app is a special device admin that cannot be deactivated by the user, once activated as a device admin. It also cannot be uninstalled. <--- , I just want to know how to set  my app as owner app

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html for more.

Comment: The one who uses your app shall be the admin not (you) the developer, so don't think you can make such app which can not be uninstalled!

Comment: Please read the given link there it's mentioned about owner app and not me i just want to know how it is possible.

Comment: For making your app as device owner without rooting device follow [Device Owner on Android 5.0 (and others) without rooted devices, device provisioning by NFC][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906210/device-owner-on-android-5-0-and-others-whitout-rooted-devices-device-provisio/27009164#27009164

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There's actually a way other than NFC and rooting to set an application as a device owner app.
You could use the **dpm** command line tool from an `adb shell`.

**Usage :**

```
usage: dpm [subcommand] [options]
usage: dpm set-device-owner <COMPONENT>
usage: dpm set-profile-owner <COMPONENT> <USER_ID>

dpm set-device-owner: Sets the given component as active admin, and its package as device owner.
dpm set-profile-owner: Sets the given component as active admin and profile owner for an existing user.
```

**UPDATE :** The `dpm` utility is really simple actually. Its goal is to create  a new file called `device_owner.xml` under `/data/system/device_owner.xml` that references the *Device/Profile owner* apps.

The Android platform is then reading this file to check which application is considered as a *Device Owner* or *Profile Owner App*.

**On a rooted device**, you could indeed [create this file by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183328/how-to-make-my-app-a-device-owner/27909315#answer-26839548), but since the `dpm` tool is doing it, you'd better use it (DRY principle) :

**For example** via a `Runtime.exec()` command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner com.foo.deviceowner/.DeviceAdminRcvr");
```

Also notice that this tool is working only if no account is set for the user (make sure no account is set in *Settings > Accounts*) before its use.

*Source and more information* at [Android shell command tool : Device Policy Manager](http://florent-dupont.blogspot.fr/2015/01/android-shell-command-dpm-device-policy.html)

Comment: The use of the **dpm** command is done through a `adb shell` command, so you first need to provision your device, enable developer mode, enable debugging, install your app as usual (install it with Android Studio for example) and then set it as a device owner app with `dpm`. You can consider the command `dpm` as a tool to facilitate your development of device/profile owner apps.

Comment: This solution cannot be used in production but is perfect for development.

Comment: @Hartok Why do you say this can't be used in production?  Any solution that doesn't require rooting the device seems better suited for production deployments.

Comment: The solution requires to enable debugging tools on the targeted device, for adb.

Comment: That's typically how enterprise applications are installed.

Comment: Good and short answer which helped me a lot! I just want to add that there are more implementation details that are not shown, such as adding the device admin receiver code, that is required to make the dpm command work. FYI. http://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-3-android-lollipop/

Comment: When doing the steps mentiond above I get the following error message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set device owner but device is already provisioned.

Comment: For me, dpm command only worked when specifying the component name like this:
com.example.app/.DeviceOwnerReceiver
The part after / is the name of the class that extends 
DeviceAdminReceiver

Comment: @AndyB you're right. I've updated the article to fix the error.

Comment: When I call from the commandline "adb shell dpm set-device-owner BLAH" things work fine (my app becomes device owner - I don't get a security exception because my app is a system app), but when I call from my program "Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dpm set-device-owner BLAH");" I get a silent failure (not a SecurityException, though I wish I got some feedback). Any idea why?

Comment: Just to add this is run in normal mode, not in recovery mode which I tried it under first

Comment: How do you know what the component name is?

Comment: That's name of the package you set in the manifest.xml of your application. see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: how to provision my app as device admin for production purpose?

Comment: Why doesn't the documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin) say anything about these steps? It gives rather the impression that the admin app should just work by normal distribution (Play Store, Email, etc.).

Comment: In later Android versions, you are forced to create an owner account when first provisioning your tablet, which renders set-device-owner useless since it complains about already existing device owner. And you cannot delete this owner account either.

Comment: Did anyone try to deploy device owner app using Samsung Knox MDM Portal?

Comment: Where can I find ```<COMPONENT>``` value?

Answer (score 19):

If you're root on your device, you can follow this method to become device owner.

First, create a file `device_owner.xml` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<device-owner package="your.owner.app.package.id" name="Your app name" />
```

Now do the following steps

1. `adb push device_owner.xml /sdcard/`
2. `adb shell`
3. `su`
4. `cp /sdcard/device_owner.xml /data/system/`
5. `cd /data/system/`
6. `chown system:system device_owner.xml`
7. reboot

Note : Before rebooting device, make sure that you installed the application, which you are trying to make device owner. If you will not do, you will get boot animation for infinite time.

Comment: For rooting the device follow: http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/chainfire-releases-quick-root-fix-android-5-0-lollipop-preview-builds-how-install-1470680

Comment: but will this work if there is an (Gmail)account already associated with the device.

Comment: @piyush this is not related to that at all and does work regardless

Comment: @Spynet thankyou for your last step, reboot, i was struggling to get it working off another guide not realising i had to reboot for it to take effect....

Comment: Hi, Whether the XML format is correct? Because I'm going to test the same in one of my device.

Comment: I am tried this on Android 10 but not working.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

On my Android 7.1.2 set-top box (AOSF and rooted), I found a couple things that have evolved over time.

1. `exec("dpm set-device-owner ...")` throws and exception unless `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_ADMINS" />` is declared in the AndroidManifest.xml.  But that brings other issues, more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674921/running-dpm-with-runtime-exec).
2. The file `/data/system/device_policy.xml` doesn't appear anymore.  Instead, it's now `/data/system/device_policy_2.xml` and the schema is slightly different. Running `dpm set-device-owner com.myDomain.myPackage/.myComponent` through an adb shell generates the file as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root>
    <device-owner package="com.myDomain.myPackage" name="" component="com.myDomain.myPackage/com.myDomain.myPackage.myComponent" userRestrictionsMigrated="true" />
</root>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use reflexivity, by calling the `DevicePolicyManager` method called `setProfileOwner` which was hidden in the SDK Documentation.

Don't forget to cancel it otherwise you'll have some conflicts with the Google Play ;)

Answer (score -4):

Just tried, and the `dpm` command requires root privilege on real devices(Samsung T550 for example), otherwise it will fail with `SecurityException`. `adb shell` only grants root on android emulators. So you will have to root the device first.

Comment: The OP is asking for a method other that "rooting" the device.

Comment: That's not true on a Nexus 5, dpm works fine for me *WITHOUT* root access, I suspect it's more likely due to some sort of customisation on that specific Samsung device.

Comment: I had the same issue (with the same device) and the problem is not that Samsung requires you to root the device. There are Samsung specific permissions (see link) that need to be set in the manifest for device owner to work. I had to add the permission `com.sec.enterprise.permission.CUSTOM_PROKIOSK` to the manifest. https://seap.samsung.com/html-docs/android-customization/Content/KNOX-Customization-SDK-Developer-Guide/To-check-required-permissions.htm

Comment: Root and/or special permissions are not required on all Samsung devices.  I have set up a device owner with adb and via QR code provisioning without special permissions or root.