# Screen pinning as device owner not working

Tags: android, android-screen-pinning

I'm trying to build a kiosk app using android 5's screen pinning feature. It seems that all I need to do in the app was to call `startLockTask()`, but this still allows the user to leave the app by pressing the recent and back buttons.

To pin the app in a way that does not allow the user to leave it requires the app to be a device owner. Based on [sites such as this one](http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-kiosk-mode-without-root/), one needs to run

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner my.package.name/.MyAdminReceiver
```

in order to set the device owner. However, that command failed with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set device owner but device is already provisioned.
```

which, I heard, is caused by the file `/data/system/device_owner.xml` already being present on the device.

Since the device had just been freshly factory-reset, I suspect that it had come with an app already provisioned by the manufacturer, so I rooted the device. I would rather do it without rooting (since there will be some 70 devices I have to run the procedure on) but for research purposes, it can't be helped.

After rooting the device, I tried to find the `device_owner.xml` file but it wasn't there. I tried creating one anyway based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26839548/353478), but the app still shows the pinning message and the recent+back buttons still unpinned the app.

So why can't I set the device owner? is there any way around it?

Comment: Does the device have a google account attached? You need to remove it before you can set the device owner.

Comment: @basilisk It didn't have a google account when I tried the dpm method. It was freshly reset. Literally the second thing I did after the device booted up after being reset (first was to install the APK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that I tried dpm provisioning on a newly reset device, @basilisk's comment hinted me at the answer. The device comes loaded with bloatware that provides default accounts. Disabling these apps finally allowed me to provision the device with dpm.

Comment: how do you actually remove all accounts.

Comment: I disabled all apps that are providing those accounts

Comment: like gmail app,