# How can I set device_owner to my android app?

Tags: android, kiosk, device-owner

I tried to set my application the device_owner of my tablet (without ROOT or NFC), with the command:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.test.my_device_owner_app/.MyDeviceAdminReceiver
```

like is written on many sites (because i have to make a KIOSK APP). First of all i made a factory reset, then i installed my app, and then i wrote this command on shell, but the answer is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to set device owner but device
>   is already provisioned.
>     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1554)
>     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
>     at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.setDeviceOwner(IDevicePolicyManager.java:3212)
>     at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.runSetDeviceOwner(Dpm.java:114)
>     at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.onRun(Dpm.java:82)
>     at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
>     at com.android.commands.dpm.Dpm.main(Dpm.java:38)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:249)

Now, how can i resolve this problem without rooting the tablet?

Comment: did you figure out how to solve the problem? I have the lenovo a10-30. Seems like there is a hidden account that lenovo creates during setup so it says the device is already provisioned.

Comment: nope....at the moment i still cannot set device_owner on this tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with Lenovo Yoga 2 Tablet.

Here is some snipped of the dpm source that I found while researching this problem.

```
    if (!allowedToSetDeviceOwnerOnDevice()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Trying to set device owner but device is already provisioned.");
    }

    if (mDeviceOwner != null && mDeviceOwner.hasDeviceOwner()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Trying to set device owner but device owner is already set.");
    }
```

And here is the `allowedToSetDeviceOwnerOnDevice` implementation

```
/**
 * Device owner can only be set on an unprovisioned device, unless it was initiated by "adb", in
 * which case we allow it if no account is associated with the device.
 */
private boolean allowedToSetDeviceOwnerOnDevice() {
    int callingId = Binder.getCallingUid();
    if (callingId == Process.SHELL_UID || callingId == Process.ROOT_UID) {
        return AccountManager.get(mContext).getAccounts().length == 0;
    } else {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.DEVICE_PROVISIONED, 0) == 0;
    }
}
```

So first make sure that all accounts are removed. Check Settings > Accounts. Lenovos bloat ware has created the *Local Calendar* account by default. You have to remove it.

**For those who have root access**

See the [SO answer for manually creating the device_owner.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183328/how-to-make-my-app-a-device-owner#answer-26839548). As I can see from the implementation, dpm is doing the same thing as described in the answer. By the way, I leave the name attribute with no problems.

When you look in the `else` case, you can bypass the test by calling

```
settings put global device_provisioned 0
```

**My experience with Yoga tablet**

Even I have root access, doing factory reset and trying the device_owner.xml method I haven't success yesterday.

What I've done today was to login with a google account (yesterday I've skipped this part) and after remove also this account in Settings > Accounts I was able (as *su*) to run the `dpm` command successfully.

**Update**

I've got another Yoga 2 tablet without root access and without login with my google account and have successfully set the device owner.

One think I can recommend you: Try to close Android Studio after installing your kiosk mode app. Maybe this causes another `Binder.getCallingUid()`.