# Access getDeviceID() for a Device Owner App Android 10?

Tags: android, imei, device-owner, android-device-owner

I have many phones I need to register in a database with IMEI barcodes and install a company app on it to connect and track them. For this purpose I need to access the IMEI with getDeviceID(). Since Android 10, it is not as simple.

In this page, Android says if you are device owner you can access it : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

I use this method to make my app a device owner app :
[How to make my app a device owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183328/how-to-make-my-app-a-device-owner)

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.package.name/.MyDeviceAdminReceiver
```

When I use getDeviceId() in the app, I still have the error :

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: The user 10180 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
```

Why this method doesn't work ?
Do you have any suggestions to the IMEI ?

Comment: you need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

Comment: Did you solve this? I have same issue and I have added the permission above.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your application as device owner is not sufficient, you also need it to complete the provisioning flow. For Android up to 11 it is started by **launching** [ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_DEVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#ACTION_PROVISION_MANAGED_DEVICE), for Android 12 you have to **listen** to [ACTION_GET_PROVISIONING_MODE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#ACTION_GET_PROVISIONING_MODE)

Google provides a [sample DPC](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc).