# Do I need to make my android app a profile owner app, or have special carrier permissions to use IMEI number. What do I require to achieve it ??

Tags: android, permissions, android-10.0, telephonymanager, imei

According to docs:
[image]

> P.S. I know it is a bad practice, but that's my client's requirement.

My client app requires IMEI number as parameter in an API call, to identify Vehicle owner in an android app.
But I have two problems :

1. READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE Permission is only granted to system apps.

[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

2. Using getDeviceId to get device identifiers is not recommended.

> 'getter for deviceId: String!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, for this kind of values (serial number, mac address) in Android 10+ only way is having your app as Device Owner.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183328/how-to-make-my-app-a-device-owner) to set a Device Owner app.